# Laravel email, pass variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mail

I am trying to build emails in Laravel, and I have a trouble with this one, I want to send email every Monday therefore I want to trigger it as a command and schedule it (unless there is a better way?) Here's my email:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

    class MondayEmails extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;

        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $events = Event::limit(5)
                ->orderBy('title')
                ->get();
            return $events;
        }

        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build()
        {
            return $this->from('support@dev.com')
                        ->view('emails.mondayEmail');
        }
    }
```

At this point $events does bring me back a collection.

Here's my mail view:

```
@foreach ($events as $event)
    {{ $event->title }}
@endforeach
```

and command:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Event;
use App\Mail\MondayEmails;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MondayEmail extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'email:monday';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Monday Events being send!';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        Mail::to('dev@gmail.com')->send(new MondayEmails());

    }
}
```

and when I run it I get:

> [ErrorException]   Undefined variable: events (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\liveandnow\resources\views\emails\mondayEmail.blade.php)
>
> [ErrorException]   Undefined variable: events

How can this be solved? Is this the right approach? Or you would do it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor doesn't return, it allows you to set properties to access within the classes other functions. If you try the following code in your MondayEmails class, this will allow you to access the emails returned in the constructor.

```
protected $events;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->events = Event::limit(5)
        ->orderBy('title')
        ->get();
}

public function build()
{
    $events = $this->events;
    return $this->from('support@dev.com')
                ->view('emails.mondayEmail', compact('events'));
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work ;/ [ErrorException]
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: It does actually work! I just had syntax error thansk

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this :

```
protected $events;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->events = Event::limit(5)
        ->orderBy('title')
        ->get();
}

public function build()
{
    $events = $this->events;
    return $this->from('support@dev.com')
                ->view('emails.mondayEmail')
                ->->with([
                'events' => $events,
              ]);
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!

Comment: In both of these solutions I get : [ErrorException]
  Undefined property: App\Mail\MondayEmails::$events

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Let me check it

Comment: I forgot protected $events; now I am getting [ErrorException]
  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Yes because you can not pass $events variable with view file.

Comment: same one, invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Please follow this link(https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-mailables-in-laravel-5-3)

Comment: I don't see anywhere where multiple records are passed

Comment: @PrzemekWojtas Please see last build function(https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-mailables-in-laravel-5-3#Passing%20data)

Comment: Your way would howver     $events = $this->events; is null for some reason